# When are two dictionary keys consider equal for user defined types?

Tags: python, data-structures

I was working on dictionary where user defined type objects are keys and i could not understand why for below code python interpreter (2.7) doesn't throw error even though below object are equal :

```
class DTest:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
    def __eq__(self,other):
        return self.name == other.name
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.name)
ob = DTest('kkk')
ob1 = DTest('kkk')
dict = {ob:1,ob1:2}
```

P.S. :  I am C++ developer who started to work on python

Comment: You can put a key multiple times into a dictionary. The older will just be overwritten.

Comment: There is just 1 item in the dictionary. Python silently removed the older entry. Unlike C++, it is not an error to inject same entry in dictionary in Python.

Comment: Just a quick note that using a mutable object as a dictionary key is *usually* a bad idea.

Comment: @jedwards how we can make user defined object as immutable and why interpreter throws error if we make python mutable datastructures (set/list) as key but behaves differently for user defined types

Comment: Also, dictionary keys are required to implement `__hash__` and `__eq__` as you've noted, but for different reasons -- `__hash__` helps determine the "bucket", while `__eq__` determines whether the keys are the same (and thus the value should be overwritten) or they're not the same (and you have a hash collision and *both* should be stored.  (`__eq__` has a default implementation btw (equivalent to `is`), while `__hash__` does not).

Comment: Mutable types are usually a bad idea for dictionary keys because they can be mutated after they've been used to insert items into a dictionary, but the dictionary won't know this, and if you try to look up the (new) value later, the dictionary won't be able to "find" it.

Answer (score 0):

```
class DTest:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
    def __eq__(self,other):
        return self.name == other.name
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.name)
ob = DTest('kkk')
ob1 = DTest('kkk')
d = {ob:1,ob1:2}
```

If you check the number of items in dictionary, it is only 1.

```
len(d)
```

gives result as 1.

Python silently overwrites the previous entry. Note, this is different from C++, where your 2nd key won't be inserted.

Comment: And please do **not** use `dict` as a variable name. That will silently overwrite the Python function by the same name!

Comment: I was just about to say the same thing! OP, I will edit my answer to not use this name.

Comment: @user2357112 , it won't be. Thank you. Made the correction.

Answer (score 0):

In response to your questions in comments, here's an example showing why mutable types are *usually* a bad idea for dictionary keys:

```
class MutableIntKey:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.val == other.val

    def __hash__(self):
        return self.val

k = MutableIntKey(5)

d = {k: "Five"}
print(d)        # {<__main__.MutableIntKey object at 0x00000249DFBFA400>: 'Five'}
print(k in d)   # True
```

Everything works so far, but what if the key is mutated...

```
# Mutate k
k.val = 600

print(d)        # {<__main__.MutableIntKey object at 0x00000249DFBFA400>: 'Five'}
print(k in d)   # False
```

Now, the dictionary doesn't "think" the key is present in the dictionary.

But really, the key *is* there...

```
print(k in list(d.keys()))  # True
```

Now, making a user-defined object immutable isn't the easiest thing in the world, but really what you care about is that the dict key is immutable.  Specifically, you want to ensure that the properties of your dict key that are used in `__hash__` and `__eq__` either immutable, or somehow otherwise protected from change.

The easiest, but least flexible approach is to use reference equality as your `__eq__` test (default), and use `id(self)` for the `__hash__` implementation.  This will ensure that, even if mutated, the key will be found.  The downside is that the only way you can lookup a key in a dictionary is if you already have a reference to that exact object.

Another way is to simply not mutate the object you're using for a key after you've used it for a key somewhere.  Possibly not the most intuitive or robust, but would certainly work.

Another way is to create an immutable object using the relevant user-defined object state, and use that as a key.  A bit of a waste of memory but simple and gets the job done.

Another might be to use descriptors on the important attributes (those being evaluated as part of the `__eq__` and `__hash__` methods) to prevent them from being easily modified.

I'm sure there are many other approaches, so it's just important that you're aware of the the process for looking keys up in a dictionary.

Comment: ID-based hashes work fine with pickling. The IDs will be different in an unpickled dict, but the dict will recompute the hashes anyway, so you don't end up with objects in the wrong hash table slot or anything like that.

Comment: I was actually just testing that myself -- thanks for the note - will update the post.